# How to wget Youtube horrible URL

Tags: shell, wget

I'm going to wget youtube search page where the URL is horrible. This is example when searching `searchkeyword` sorted by upload date:

```
wget http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=videos&search_query=searchkeyword&search_sort=video_date_uploaded&suggested_categories=26%2C27%2C22%2C28%2C24
```

and this one is page 2 of the search result:

```
wget http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=videos&search_query=searchkeyword&search_sort=video_date_uploaded&suggested_categories=26%2C27%2C22%2C28%2C24&page=2
```

The wget give me misleading page for both pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrapping the URL in single quotation marks should do the trick. Also, you will want to give a name to the downloaded file as well (otherwise it will have the weird name that `wget` guessed from the URL). So

```
wget 'http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=videos&search_query=searchkeyword&search_sort=video_date_uploaded&suggested_categories=26%2C27%2C22%2C28%2C24' -O nice_name.html
```

Explanation as per laebshade's comment (thanks for reminding me): The many funny characters in the URL will be interpreted by the [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) as special commands or other control sequences. From the top of my head, ~ ! # ^ & * will all mean something else to the shell (depends on what shell you are using). You can use `\` to escape them one by one, or quote the whole thing.

Comment: It would be good to explain the reason for using quotes.

The reason it's not giving you the right URL is because the URL contains an '&' (ampersand) character, which your shell interprets as a `fork()` to background; in other words, your shell sends the first part of the command `wget http://youtube.com/results?search_type=videos&` to the background, then treats the next part of the "command" as a new one, until it reaches another `&`, and so on and so forth.

Comment: @laebshade Very helpful explanation. :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `wget` for downloading individual pages. It is better suited for things like recursive downloads of whole sites. Try `curl` instead.

Also, make sure you quote your arguments on the command line so that you don't run into shell globing problems with characters like `?`.

```
curl 'http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=videos&search_query=searchkeyword&search_sort=video_date_uploaded&suggested_categories=26%2C27%2C22%2C28%2C24&page=2' \
    > results.html
```

Comment: Instead of `> results.html` you can also use `curl http:://url.com/randompage -o results.html`

Comment: Perfect:  Curl obviously has different magic embedded.  ^wget^curl made it work in my case (pulling a JSON file of a google spreadsheet.) Hat's off to you Good Sir!

Answer (score 3):

Use **youtube-dl** for downloading Youtube videos.  It's a epic python script.  It req's Python.  If you have Ubuntu, install with this command: `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` otherwise you can directly download it from the website: http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/